# Google Glass wifi hotspot

Tags: arduino, android-wifi, google-glass

I need to turn my Google Glass as a Wifi Hotspot in order to send data from Glass to my Wifi Shield (Arduino).

Is it possible to set my Glass as a wifi hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

Google Glass can not work as a hotspot.
You could use a smartphone as hotspot and connect the Glass and arduino to that, then they can talk to each other over that network

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You cannot expect it to perform as your laptop or phone because instead of full-circuit card that supports 802.11 b/g/n with several antennas, Glass has only one wireless module on its board. That is from a Taiwanese company with module number WM-BN-BM-04 .

You can see the details [about that module here](https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/QLI_viewQDL.cfm?qid=20329) or you can even buy it from [Alibaba for $10](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/WM-BN-BM-04-A-USI-WIFI-Module/1598311438.html) ;) . Even built-in apps such as video call doesn't run smoothly most probably because of this limited hardware.. But a bigger problem about Glass Wifi is that it only supports WEP -hackable by high school students- and WPA/WPA2. No enterprise. You can have a WIFI connection at home but unfortunately not at university, work etc. So with this in mind, you should probably design only at-home applications with WIFI.